# dynamic populating of data in JSP form (struts)

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsp, struts2

My requirement : I have a form with select and 3 text boxes. When I select a particular option from select. I need to go to action class which will hit the DB and get three strings. These 3 strings has to be populated in the 3 text boxes DYNAMICALLY .

My Problem: ( Myself being new to J2EE will be the first ) I have tried with STRUTS2 and JQUERY (AJAX). The below code will give you an idea what i have tried. My problem is that I have no idea how to send my request to action class and get that response. (with just struts I used member variables for request and taglib for response ;like s:property val)

Action Class

```
package com.zayn.wsrdetails;  
public class SelectProjectAction {  
private String data1;  
private String data2;  
private String data3;  
private String proj;  

public String execute()  
{  
    System.out.println("Hey dude Execute runs");  
    String tempVal2=getProj();  
    String check="Project1";  
    if(proj.equals(check))  
    {  
        setData1("ID191");  
        setData2("DG");  
        setData3("100PDS");  
    }  
    System.out.print(tempVal2);  
    return "Success";  
}  
}
```

Struts  XML

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts    
Configuration 2.1//EN" "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.1.dtd">  
<struts>  
<package name="ProjectSelect" extends="struts-default">   
<action name="Project" class="com.zayn.wsrdetails.SelectProjectAction">   
<result name="Success">/MainPage.jsp</result>  
</action>  
</package>  
</struts>
```

JSP page

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"  
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>  
  <%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>  
<!DOCTYPE html>  


<html>  
<head>  
<title>WSR</title>  
<script src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>  
<script>  
$(document).ready(function(){  

    $("#prj_change").change(function(){  
        var optionSelected = $("option:selected", this).val();  
        alert ("change event occured with value: " + optionSelected);  
          $.ajax({  
                 url:'Project',  
                 data:optionSelected,  
                 success: function(response){  
                     alert ("change event occured with value: " + optionSelected);  
                 }  
});  
});  
});  

</script>  
</head>  

<body>  
<form action="Project" method="post">  
<select id="prj_change">  
  <option value="None">None</option>  
  <option value="Project1">Project1</option>  
  <option value="Project2">Project2</option>  
  <option value="Project3">Project3</option>  
</select>  

<label> Project id :</label><input type="text" name="data1" id="data1"></input><br>  
<label> Project Lead :</label><input type="text" name="data2" id="data2"></input><br>  
<label> Project length :</label><input type="text" name="data3" id="data3"></input><br>  

</form>  
</body>  
</html>
```

Please let me know how i can proceed here

Answer (score 0):

your can alse passing the value this way

```
$.ajax({
      url:"Project",
      data: {"proj" : "optionSelected"},
      .............................
});
```

after getting value.simply set into textfield.

```
 $("#prj_change").change(function(){  
     var optionSelected = $("option:selected", this).val();  
     alert ("change event occured with value: " + optionSelected);
    if(){  
         $.ajax({  
              url:"Project?proj=optionSelected",  
              success: function(response){  
                 alert ("change event occured with value: " + optionSelected); 
                 $("#date1").val(<s:property value="data1"/>);
                 $("#date2").val(<s:property value="data2"/>);
                 $("#date3").val(<s:property value="data3"/>);


              }  
           });
          }else{
               slert("you are selected NONE");
                }
  });
```

Comment: $("#data1").val(<s:property value="data1"/>);
This doesnt fill the text box with the  values of data1,2,3

Comment: you don't have value attribute.so,use setattribute method.

Answer (score 0):

For this you can use simple json  method. A complete example with code is available at my site. Please refer.

[Example 1](http://tech.learnerandtutor.com/dynamic-drop-down-list-with-struts-2-and-ajax/)

[Example 2](http://tech.learnerandtutor.com/send-json-object-to-struts-2-action-by-jquery-ajax/)

[Example 3](http://tech.learnerandtutor.com/read-json-object-from-struts-2-action-by-jquery-ajax/)

Answer (score 0):

**step 1 :** first thing you need to do is to make an `onchange` method call on that `select` tag which will go to `javascript` and get the data .here you will recieve the data from the select tag and pass it to action in step 2.

**step 2 :** in that `javascript` method you need to interact with the action class to get the data .
using a redirect method ,of passing parameters in url you can do it here .also if you want to send multiple values to action then you can get the values by form name or form id and submit that form using javascript;

**step 3 :** you will get the data in the javascript and now return it to jsp page by creating a select tag using javascript or using the method to show/hide div from js and  set those values in those 2nd select tag..

also if you want your javascript to go and get data from java you can also use `DWR`

the flow will go like this...i would suggest you to follow this flow so that you can learn being a newbie.all the best